# Tags section has different view in different content types in Drupal 8.1.1

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-content-types

I am new in `Drupal` and other web concepts. I have installed `Drupal 8.1.1` and everything is OK. It has a default content type called `Article`. I add another content type called `Project`. in `Manage Fields` section I click on `Add Field` button, then from the box `Re-use an existing field`, I choose `Entity reference: field_tags` option. The problem is in `Edit` page for this added field, I see another view for tags section.

Here the `Project` content type:

[image]
And here is the `Article` content type:

[image]

As you see the default value sections is different. So what is the problem and how can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily a problem, unless you need to enter multiple default values for your article content type.

The default value form for the field instance is dependent on the *cardinality*, or number of values the field can contain.

If you wish to change the cardinality, you will need to do so when editing the field base, and it cannot be changed once values have been added to the field on your content types. You can do this when adding a field, or by editing the field when there is no data entered across your content types.

If you are looking at the Edit view when creating one of your content types and wish to change the way the field's form looks, you may do so by editing the content type's Form Display setting for that field, and change the field display type there.